# FIFO Cost Calculation

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

Namaskaram,

I am developing a Retail POS application in Java Swing with H2 database. For calculating the cost, I need help.

FIFO Cost Calculation

- I have the following tables
- Purchase Table

[image]

- Sale Table

[image]

- FIFOCost Table

[image]

My requirement is to calculate Average Cost of each sold Item, into the FIFOCost Table.

Values to insert into FIFOCost table can be done, programmatically, whenever an insert happens in Sale Table. But, when any updates(like editing the Item or its Qty) happen in both Purchase and Sale table after few weeks or months (which requires FIFOCost Table, also to be updated, with huge volume of datas)

Currently, I am accomplishing through program itself. I am looking for a solution, where little programming and more work in database itself, using advanced tools like recursive.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Purchase` table? What is the algorithm for getting the `AvgCost` in the `FIFOCost` table?

Comment: the purpose of Purchase table is to store purchase data. The AvgCost column in FIFOCost table shows the average of Cost from Purchase table for each inserts of SaleTable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a QtySold column to your purchase table, and wade through the following algorithm on each sale:

```
qty_left = sale_qty
tot_cost = 0;     
while qty_left > 0
   fetch oldest row where qty_sold < qty
   if qty_left + qty_sold < qty
   then 
        set qty_sold = qty_sold + qty_left
        tot_cost = tot_cost + (Purchase.Cost * qty_left)
        qty_left = 0
   else
        qty_at_this_cost = qty - qty_sold
        set qty_sold = qty
        tot_cost = tot_cost + (Purchase.cost * qty_at_this_cost)
        qty_left = qty_left - qty_at_this_cost 

avg_cost = tot_cost / sale_qty
```

While it might be possible to do this with recursive SQL it would be neither efficient or readable.

You could possibly persuade your user to use the much more sensible and easier to calculate moving average cost.

i.e. everytime you purchase new stock you calculate
    MVC = ((Current Stock * MVC) + (New Stock * New Cost)) / (Current Stock + New Stock)

This is similar but it averages out costs over all purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somewhere be keeping track of inventory on hand. When a sale occurs, you are going to do several things: Look at the number of items sold vs the amount of inventory on hand. For example, lets look at the second sale, 487. You sold 10 apples @ $16.00. The first part of your function would query where the Item = Apple and OnHand >= 0. It would first come to item 101, which would have an OH of 5. Calculate the cost of goods sold using those 5 items at 11.00 each and update the inventory on hand to 0.  You then again would have to query looking for Item = Apple, and onHand >= 0 and then use 5 from Item 195, adding that cost of goods sold to the number you calculated in the first part, and update the inventory on hand for that item.